# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()I

Tags: spring

Acabo de comenzar a aprender spring y ya me tope con el primer problema el cual creo q necesito una ayuda, siguo un curso pero manejan otro ide propio de spring, y yo lo estoy realizando en eclipse. 
error me arroja java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()I    quisiera saber como solucionar esto. saludos y gracias.

HomeController

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="home", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String goHome(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Udemy</groupId>
<artifactId>cinema</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

springmvc-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.udemy.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: ¿Cuándo da el error? ¿al hacer un maven clean install o al hacer deploy de la aplicación e intenar acceder a ella?

Answer (score 1):

el problema era de la version de mi tomcat, estaba la 6.0 y spring 5.0. cambie el tomcat a 9.0 y dejo el error mostrado. dejo la respuesta para otros principiantes. gracias